# Is mysql_connect() usable in PHP 5.6.5

Tags: php, version, deprecated, mysql-connect

Which is the latest version PHP version, who support mysql_connect()?

I've want to upgrade my PHP version. I've read, that mysql_connect() are deprecated. In all Projects I've use the old mysql_connect(). Can I update to PHP 5.6.5 or is the command in this version removed already?

Uses somebody PHP 5.6.5 with mysql_connect()?

Problem is, that I can't change sooo much Projects in this short time and could only update to the highest version, which support mysql_connect().

Best regards and many thanks!

Comment: *"Is mysql_connect() usable in PHP 5.6.5"* - **A:** *No'ish,* and [error reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) will tell you. Use `mysqli_` or PDO. If you get a warning, then you'll have no choice but to switch.

Comment: It's still available in 5.6.x, with depreciation notice. In future versions it's likely to become an external PECL module.

Comment: To answer the question at hand, there is a piece of code I remember seeing on Stack/web that will detect whether the functions are deprecated and if so, use the respective API. You just need to look for it.

Comment: Sorry! I don't find the same question with answer. I've read, that I'll get a deprecation notice. But if I get a notice, then I could use the function?! In future I will/must use the mysqli, but I must take an update now and must use the php version, where mysql_connect() are usuable (notices I can deactivate). But I can't change sooo many codelines to mysqli_* in this short time....

Comment: Instead of just changing it all to mysqli_ directly, create your own database class that uses mysqli_ inside, so when you decide to finally move to PDO you only have to change the internals of that wrapper and not every page's code.

Comment: Now I found my answer in one of the answers of your linked thread (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). I've don't look at these question, because I thought, this question is still another one and too generally. It seems, that I could use mysql_connect() to 5.7. ;-)

Comment: @developerwjk correct! all new projects uses an own sql class. but the old projects are coded hard and I can't update the server and tomorrow I must change 100 projects with a few thousends codelines... - it isn't possible. therefore I asked in which version the mysql_connect() isn't usable anymore... :-)

Answer (score 8):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php

> 5.5.0     This function will generate an E_DEPRECATED error.

don't try to use any **mysql_*** functions as they are deprecated and dangerous. See **mysqli_** functions instead.

Comment: Very well formatted "comment". Wish I could do that in one.

Comment: PDO is preferable to MySQLi IMHO.

Comment: UV, *huh* ? - wow, wish I'd of put [my comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28202250/is-mysql-connect-usable-in-php-5-6-5#comment44770740_28202250) as one. I'd of gotten 2 also! wow Edit: Make that 3.

Comment: There is no need to be sarcastic and mean. I was writing this comment the same time as you were.

Comment: Questions like these shouldn't have answers, IMHO. They're all over Stack and the web. I mean come on, really. Plus, PHP 5.6 - `mysql_` to be deleted in future releases. 5.6 IS a future release.

Comment: I think the OP already knew all the info in this answer. They were asking for a way around these facts.

Comment: @developerwjk Therefore not "answering" the *real* question asked.